# Конвертация строки из UTF8 в ANSI

Tags: java, кодировка

Как в *Java* конвертировать строку из `UTF8` в `ANSI`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try
{
    String utf8String = new String("абвгд".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String ansiString = new String(utf8String.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception)
{
    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
}
```